# How to allow local resource to remote server i.e., ports

Tags: server, rds

I need help with allow local ports to the remote computer.
This is the Windows 10 workstation trying to launch the Remote APP on Session Host server on Windows server 2012 R2.
On Terminal server. for Collection properties there is no option for 
[image]

This is while launching the RemoteApp on Internet explorer on Windows10 machine. There is no option to enable ports her.
[image]

I would appreciate for you helping me in this issue I really need this to be working.